# JavaScript keypress or keyup to control key value

Tags: javascript

In my project inputText box **keypress or keyup** event call maxlimit function in this function check current value is greater than to max limit value to remove current  keynum value.
(i.e)  I set max limit is 23 then I type 22 to allowed

And now textbox is value **22** ,then I type **212** need to remove 1 only. otherwsie **322** to remove **3** only, not clear to  whole text. Is this possible?

**Javascript**

```
 function hour(id, e) 
 { 
     var keynum; 
     if (window.event) // IE
      { 
          keynum = e.keyCode; 
      } 
      else if (e.which) 
      {
          keynum = e.which; 
      } 
      if (id !== undefined) 
      {
          console.info("Text box Value : " + id.value); 
          console.info("Charcter key press value : " + String.fromCharCode(keynum)); 
           console.info("Now Key press Position :"+id.value.indexOf(keynum));
          var currentValue = id.value + String.fromCharCode(keynum); 
          console.info("Combine value :"+currentValue); 

          if (currentValue > 23)
          { 
            ............... 
          } 
      } 
      else 
      {
              ............
      }
 }
```

Comment: Not exactly related, but `if (window.event)` is not a reliable IE check, Chrome has implemented global event object too.

Comment: Also, getting a character from `keyCode/which` is not reliable. E.g. the code will fail when entering numbers on number pad.

Answer (score 0):

`if (currentValue > 22) {
     currentValue = 22;
}`

should do the trick. 212 will be set to 22, 332 will be set to 22, 999 will be set to 22 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input=document.getElementById('input');

input.oninput=function(){
  if(parseInt(input.value)>parseInt(input.max))
    input.value=input.max;
  };
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" max="22">
```